# Laravel Error - Base table or view not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to run this code I cloned, but I keep getting this error..

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'roocket.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `permissions`)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'roocket.permissions' doesn't exist-Vue-Dashboard/blob/master/src/pages/Pages/RTLPage.vue
```

I have run `composer install` and `npm install` , and I am new to the laravel world.

I have uploaded the repo to my github https://github.com/arya107/laravelbackend.
I have connected the DB via XAMPP and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: In DB you need to create a table with name permissions, (the migration file miss for the table permissions)

Comment: Did you run the migrations?

Comment: ErDiablo what do you mean?

Comment: I think you forget about table permissions. On your github migration I didn't found it. Your problem say there no this tables. You can just try my solution may be it help

Comment: nothing is being imported into the DB

Answer (score 4):

Basically, the fix for me was that I needed to comment out

```
      {
        Gate::define($permission->name , function ($user) use($permission){
            return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
        });
      }
```

Then, I was enabled to install it, and then I re-enabled the code :)

Comment: Had this exact same issue as well in my App/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php. Goofy, but works..

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan migrate
```

You are missing the DB table. Run the migrations included in the project to create the tables in your DB.

Comment: Did the command work? Did you get the tables in your DB or you got an error?

Comment: Can you run `php artisan config:cache` and then the migrate command again?

Comment: same error `  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'roocket.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `permissions`)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'roocket.permissions' doesn't exist`

Comment: I cloned this project, can you tell me how to make the migration please?

Comment: Sorry the table should be created the migration exists in 2017_06_04_055720_create_roles_table.php migration. When running the migrate command does ANY table at all created? Is your .env file set to connect to your local db?

Comment: yeah I have connected it, I get this error and I am not able to migrate

Answer (score 0):

The [migration](https://github.com/arya107/laravelbackend/blob/master/database/migrations/2017_06_04_055720_create_roles_table.php) is creating the field and relationship at same time. I would try to use separated migrations, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028227/laravel-multiple-tables-per-migration) answer explains:

> But I always create a foreign key in a separate Schema::table() command, because some databases need you to have the column before attaching the constraint to it

I think (haven't tried it) that your database engine does not accept the creation of the foreign key relation because the FK field was not created yet.

You can also try to do a full migrate using:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

That command will drop all your database tables, so be careful!